# You are neither in a module nor in your GOPATH

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I was really bothered by a Golang problem,I use vscode-remote to develop Go project,when I want to create a go project not in GOPATH,when I input a letter,the Go extension will warn me that **You are neither in a module nor in your GOPATH. Please see https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules for information on how to set up your Go project.**,I really don`t know how to fix it,and I also foud that for some files,the gopls works,but for another,it will not work,what can I do!

Comment: What go command you are trying to run? You might want to run `go mod init` command to initiate module in your project directory.

Answer (score -2):

If you are going to create a project not into go path then you can temporarily make your project as go path and all the source code you write can be put into the src folder. Open up your terminal and export GOPATH=your_proj_directory